# Java Mouse Program Wrong Output

Tags: java, arrays

I'm working on a java program that is supposed to print a 2D array and a "mouse" needs to randomly move across the array. If the mouse hits the edge of the array, it tests if the number that it hits is a -1 (mouse escapes array) or a -2 (mouse dies). If it moves over 50 times, it dies (this whole process is repeated 1000 times in a for loop). Every time the mouse moves, it replaces the number of the array location its on with what move number its on. Example: total moves is the # of moves the mouse has done :

```
totalMoves++;
island[r][c] = totalMoves;
```

After the program is executed, it should print the last 3 lines like this:

```
# of times the mouse escaped: 222
# of times the mouse drowned: 494
# of times the mouse starved: 284
```

The numbers should also be added up to 1000 (MAX_SIMULATIONS)
*FYI, W is -2 and B is -1, but a string is printed instead.*
The problem is that instead of printing the output above, it prints the amount of times staved as 0, 1, or 2:

```
# of times the mouse escaped: 222
# of times the mouse drowned: 494
# of times the mouse starved: 0
```

I tried reading over the code OVER and OVER but couldn't find the solution. Here is my program:
OBJECT CLASS:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Mouse {
    final int NUM_ROWS = 10;
    final int NUM_COLS = 15;
    final int MAX_MOVES = 50;
    private int drown = 0;
    private int starve = 0;
    private int escape = 0;
    int[][] island = new int[NUM_ROWS][NUM_COLS];
    Random rand = new Random ();
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;




    public int getStarve()
    {

       return starve;
    }

     public int getDrown()
    {
       return drown;
    }

     public int getEscape()
    {
       return escape;
   }


    public void createIsland()
    {
       for (int r = 0; r < island.length; r++)
       {
          for (int c = 0; c < island[r].length; c++)
          {
                island[r][c] = 0;           
          }

      }
    }

    public String printIsland()
    {
        String ans = "";
       for (int r = 0; r < island.length; r++)
       {
          for (int c = 0; c < island[r].length; c++)
          {
              if(island[r][c] == -1)
              {
                  ans+= "B   ";

              }
              else if(island[r][c] == -2)
              {
                  ans+= "W   ";
              }
              else if(island[r][c]>=10)
              {
                 ans+= island[r][c] + "  ";     
              }
              else
              {
                 ans+= island[r][c] + "   ";     
              }

          }
         ans+="\n";
      }
    return ans;
    }



    public void edgeIsland() 
    {
        for(int r = 0; r<island.length;r++)
        {
            float chance = rand.nextFloat();

              if (chance <= .30f)
              {
                  island[r][0] = -1;
              }
              else
              {
                  island[r][0] = -2;
              }
        }
        for(int r = 0; r<island[0].length;r++)
        {
            float chance = rand.nextFloat();

              if (chance <= 0.30f)
              {
                  island[0][r] = -1;
              }
              else
              {
                  island[0][r] = -2;
              }
        }

        for(int r = 0; r<island[0].length;r++)
        {
            float chance = rand.nextFloat();

              if (chance <= 0.30f)
              {
                  island[9][r] = -1;
              }
              else
              {
                  island[9][r] = -2;
              }
        }
        for(int r = 0; r<island.length;r++)
        {
            float chance = rand.nextFloat();

              if (chance <= 0.30f)
              {
                  island[r][14] = -1;
              }
              else
              {
                  island[r][14] = -2;
              }
        }

    }
    int start = 0;
    public void randomStart()
    {

        start = island[4][7] += 1;
    }

        String ans = "";        
        public String getAns()
        {

            return ans;
        }

          public void mouseMov()
          {
            int moveCount = start;


             int move = rand.nextInt((4 - 1) + 1) + 1;

             for(int k = 0; k < 20; k++)
             {
                for (int i = 0; i < island.length; i++)
                {
                   for (int j = 0; j < island[i].length; j++)
                   {
                      if (island[i][j] == moveCount && moveCount <= MAX_MOVES)
                      {
                          move =  rand.nextInt((4 - 1) + 1) + 1;


                         if (move == 1)
                         {
                            if (moveCount == MAX_MOVES)
                            {

                               ans = "The mouse wandered" +  " around and starved!";
                               starve++;
                               moveCount = MAX_MOVES+1;
                               break;
                            }
                            else if (island[i][j-1] == -2)
                            {

                               ans = "The mouse drowned in" +
                               " the water!";
                               drown++;
                               moveCount++;
                               island[i][j-1] = moveCount;
                               moveCount = MAX_MOVES+1;
                               break;
                            }
                            else if (island[i][j-1] == -1)
                            {

                               ans = "The mouse found a bridge" +
                               " and escaped!";
                               escape++;
                               moveCount++;
                               island[i][j-1] = moveCount;
                               moveCount = MAX_MOVES+1;
                               break;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                moveCount++;
                               island[i][j-1] = moveCount;
                            }
                         }
                         else if (move == 2)
                         {
                            if (moveCount == MAX_MOVES)
                            {

                               ans = "The mouse wandered" +
                              " around and starved!";
                               starve++;
                               moveCount = MAX_MOVES+1;
                               break;
                            }
                            else if (island[i][j+1] == -2)
                            {

                               ans = "The mouse drowned in" +
                               " the water!";
                               drown++;
                               moveCount++;
                               island[i][j+1] = moveCount;
                               moveCount = MAX_MOVES+1;
                               break;
                            }
                            else if (island[i][j+1] == -1)
                            {

                               ans = "The mouse found a bridge" +
                               " and escaped!";
                               escape++;
                               moveCount++;
                               island[i][j+1] = moveCount;
                               moveCount = MAX_MOVES+1;
                               break;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                moveCount++;
                               island[i][j+1] = moveCount;

                            }
                         }
                         else if (move == 3)
                         {
                            if (moveCount == MAX_MOVES)
                            {

                               ans = "The mouse wandered" +
                                  " around and starved!";
                               starve++;
                               moveCount = MAX_MOVES+1;
                               break;
                            }
                            else if (island[i-1][j] == -2)
                            {

                               ans = "The mouse drowned in" +
                               " the water!";
                               drown++;
                               moveCount++;
                               island[i-1][j] = moveCount;
                               moveCount = MAX_MOVES+1;
                               break;
                            }
                            else if (island[i-1][j] == -1)
                            {

                               ans = "The mouse found a bridge" +
                               " and escaped!";
                               escape++;
                               moveCount++;
                               island[i-1][j] = moveCount;
                               moveCount = MAX_MOVES+1;
                               break;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                moveCount++;
                               island[i-1][j] = moveCount;
                            }
                         }
                         else
                         {
                            if (moveCount == MAX_MOVES)
                            {

                               ans = "The mouse wandered" +
                                  " around and starved!";
                               starve++;
                               moveCount = MAX_MOVES+1;
                               break;
                            }
                            else if (island[i+1][j] == -2)
                            {

                               ans = "The mouse drowned in" +
                               " the water!";
                               drown++;
                               moveCount++;
                               island[i+1][j] = moveCount;
                               moveCount = MAX_MOVES+1;
                               break;
                            }
                            else if (island[i+1][j] == -1)
                            {

                               ans = "The mouse found a bridge" +
                               " and escaped!";
                               escape++;
                               moveCount++;
                               island[i+1][j] = moveCount;
                               moveCount = MAX_MOVES+1;
                               break;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                moveCount++;
                               island[i+1][j] = moveCount;
                            }
                         }
                      }
                  }
              }
          }
     }
}
```

TEST CLASS:

```
public class MouseTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int NUM_SIMULATIONS = 1000;
        Mouse g = new Mouse();
        int count = 0;
        for(int c = 0;c<NUM_SIMULATIONS; c++)
        {
        g.createIsland();
        g.edgeIsland();
        g.randomStart();
        g.mouseMov();
        System.out.println(g.getAns());
        System.out.print(g.printIsland() + "\n---------------------------------------------------------\n\n");
        count++;
        }
        System.out.println(count);
        System.out.println("# of times the mouse escaped: " + g.getEscape());
        System.out.println("# of times the mouse drowned: " + g.getDrown());
        System.out.println("# of times the mouse starved: " + g.getStarve());


    }

}
```

If someone could help me fix this, it would be GREATLY appreciated. Thank you all!

Comment: First split up your code into methods. Methods should not end with seven end of block braces. This is pure debugging, if you learn how to step through your code you will quickly find an answer.

Comment: How are you doing Tristan? Have you got a working solution already? I might have a few coding tips once you are finished.

Comment: No, haven't gotten it to give the right output yet. But i'm open to your tips. I know my whole program is a big mess & it needs organization, but what do you have in mind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I now saw my error. At first, it was only moving to the right because in my for loop I set `c` as `island[r][c]` and added one to `c` each time. After fixing that I randomized each move from 1-4. If it was 1, it would go right, so `island[r][c+1]`. I did that with the rest of my moves (`island[r][c-1], island[r+1][c], and island[r-1][c]`). Now when I would output, it would print the wrong number of times the mouse escaped, and that was an extremely small and simple error. In my for loop, I had put `moveCount<20` instead of `moveCount<MAX_MOVES`! (Max moves is 50) So it would print that the mouse moved 50 times because of another loop, but it was only actually moving 20 times! Here's the ending code:

MAIN CLASS:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Mouse {
    final int NUM_ROWS = 10;
    final int NUM_COLS = 15;
    final int MAX_MOVES = 50;
    private double drown = 0;
    private double starve = 0;
    private double escape = 0;
    int[][] island = new int[NUM_ROWS][NUM_COLS];
    Random rand = new Random ();





    public double getStarve()
    {
        double starveF = starve * 10/100;
        return starveF;
    }

     public double getDrown()
    {
         double drownF = drown * 10/100;
       return drownF;
    }

     public double getEscape()
    {
         double escapeF = escape * 10/100;
       return escapeF;
   }


    public void createIsland()
    {
       for (int r = 0; r < island.length; r++)
       {
          for (int c = 0; c < island[r].length; c++)
          {
                island[r][c] = 0;           
          }

      }
    }

    public String printIsland()
    {
        String ans = "";
       for (int r = 0; r < island.length; r++)
       {
          for (int c = 0; c < island[r].length; c++)
          {
              if(island[r][c] == -1)
              {
                  ans+= "b   ";

              }
              else if(island[r][c] == -2)
              {
                  ans+= "w   ";
              }
              else if(island[r][c] == -3)
              {
                  ans+= "W   ";
              }
              else if(island[r][c] == -4)
              {
                  ans+= "B   ";
              }
              else if(island[r][c]>=10)
              {
                 ans+= island[r][c] + "  ";     
              }
              else
              {
                 ans+= island[r][c] + "   ";     
              }

          }
         ans+="\n";
      }
    return ans;
    }



    public void edgeIsland() 
    {
        for(int r = 0; r<island.length;r++)
        {
            float chance = rand.nextFloat();

              if (chance <= .30f)
              {
                  island[r][0] = -1;
              }
              else
              {
                  island[r][0] = -2;
              }
        }
        for(int r = 0; r<island[0].length;r++)
        {
            float chance = rand.nextFloat();

              if (chance <= 0.30f)
              {
                  island[0][r] = -1;
              }
              else
              {
                  island[0][r] = -2;
              }
        }

        for(int r = 0; r<island[0].length;r++)
        {
            float chance = rand.nextFloat();

              if (chance <= 0.30f)
              {
                  island[9][r] = -1;
              }
              else
              {
                  island[9][r] = -2;
              }
        }
        for(int r = 0; r<island.length;r++)
        {
            float chance = rand.nextFloat();

              if (chance <= 0.30f)
              {
                  island[r][14] = -1;
              }
              else
              {
                  island[r][14] = -2;
              }
        }

    }
    int start = 0;
    public void randomStart()
    {

        start = island[4][7] += 1;
    }

        String ans = "";        
        public String getAns()
        {

            return ans;
        }

          public void mouseMov()
          {
            int moveCount = start;


             int move = rand.nextInt((4 - 1) + 1) + 1;

             for(int k = 0; k < MAX_MOVES; k++)
             {
                for (int i = 0; i < island.length; i++)
                {
                   for (int j = 0; j < island[i].length; j++)
                   {
                      if (island[i][j] == moveCount && moveCount <= MAX_MOVES)
                      {
                          move =  rand.nextInt((4 - 1) + 1) + 1;


                         if (move == 1)
                         {
                            if (moveCount == MAX_MOVES)
                            {

                               ans = "The mouse wandered" +  " around and starved!";
                               starve++;
                               moveCount = MAX_MOVES+1;
                               break;
                            }
                            else if (island[i][j-1] == -2)
                            {

                               ans = "The mouse drowned in" +
                               " the water!";
                               drown++;
                               moveCount++;
                               island[i][j-1] = moveCount;
                               moveCount = MAX_MOVES+1;
                               island[i][j-1] = -3;
                               break;
                            }
                            else if (island[i][j-1] == -1)
                            {

                               ans = "The mouse found a bridge" +
                               " and escaped!";
                               escape++;
                               moveCount++;
                               island[i][j-1] = moveCount;
                               moveCount = MAX_MOVES+1;
                               island[i][j-1] = -4;
                               break;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                moveCount++;
                               island[i][j-1] = moveCount;
                            }
                         }
                         else if (move == 2)
                         {
                            if (moveCount == MAX_MOVES)
                            {

                               ans = "The mouse wandered" +
                              " around and starved!";
                               starve++;
                               moveCount = MAX_MOVES+1;
                               break;
                            }
                            else if (island[i][j+1] == -2)
                            {

                               ans = "The mouse drowned in" +
                               " the water!";
                               drown++;
                               moveCount++;
                               island[i][j+1] = moveCount;
                               moveCount = MAX_MOVES+1;
                               island[i][j+1] = -3;
                               break;
                            }
                            else if (island[i][j+1] == -1)
                            {

                               ans = "The mouse found a bridge" +
                               " and escaped!";
                               escape++;
                               moveCount++;
                               island[i][j+1] = moveCount;
                               moveCount = MAX_MOVES+1;
                               island[i][j+1] = -4;
                               break;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                moveCount++;
                               island[i][j+1] = moveCount;

                            }
                         }
                         else if (move == 3)
                         {
                            if (moveCount == MAX_MOVES)
                            {

                               ans = "The mouse wandered" +
                                  " around and starved!";
                               starve++;
                               moveCount = MAX_MOVES+1;
                               break;
                            }
                            else if (island[i-1][j] == -2)
                            {

                               ans = "The mouse drowned in" +
                               " the water!";
                               drown++;
                               moveCount++;
                               island[i-1][j] = moveCount;
                               moveCount = MAX_MOVES+1;
                               island[i-1][j] = -3;
                               break;
                            }
                            else if (island[i-1][j] == -1)
                            {

                               ans = "The mouse found a bridge" +
                               " and escaped!";
                               escape++;
                               moveCount++;
                               island[i-1][j] = moveCount;
                               moveCount = MAX_MOVES+1;
                               island[i-1][j] = -4;
                               break;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                moveCount++;
                               island[i-1][j] = moveCount;
                            }
                         }
                         else
                         {
                            if (moveCount == MAX_MOVES)
                            {

                               ans = "The mouse wandered" +
                                  " around and starved!";
                               starve++;
                               moveCount = MAX_MOVES+1;
                               break;
                            }
                            else if (island[i+1][j] == -2)
                            {

                               ans = "The mouse drowned in" +
                               " the water!";
                               drown++;
                               moveCount++;
                               island[i+1][j] = moveCount;
                               moveCount = MAX_MOVES+1;
                               island[i+1][j] = -3;
                               break;
                            }
                            else if (island[i+1][j] == -1)
                            {

                               ans = "The mouse found a bridge" +
                               " and escaped!";
                               escape++;
                               moveCount++;
                               island[i+1][j] = moveCount;
                               moveCount = MAX_MOVES+1;
                               island[i+1][j] = -4;
                               break;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                moveCount++;
                               island[i+1][j] = moveCount;
                            }
                         }
                      }
                  }
              }
          }
     }
}
```

TEST CLASS:

```
public class MouseTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int NUM_SIMULATIONS = 1000;
        Mouse g = new Mouse();
        for(int c = 0;c<NUM_SIMULATIONS; c++)
        {
            g.createIsland();
            g.edgeIsland();
            g.randomStart();
            g.mouseMov();
            if(c<3)
            {
                System.out.println(g.getAns());
                System.out.print(g.printIsland() + "\n---------------------------------------------------------\n\n");
            }
        }

        System.out.println("# of times the mouse escaped: " + g.getEscape()+"%");
        System.out.println("# of times the mouse drowned: " + g.getDrown()+"%");
        System.out.println("# of times the mouse starved: " + g.getStarve()+"%");

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you go over all the indices of the island, but you're not even using the `x` and `y` of the mouse in the main loop. I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but as `c` is only increasing, it is little wonder that the mouse is moving to the right.

---

Personally, I think the game is too big to just mess around with a big array. Whoever gave you that assignment is overcharging you guys. Here is a class design with the game logic missing.

Note that `Board` and `Position` are immutable classes, they don't change state (the contents of their fields is fixed after creation).

```
public final class Board {

    private static final float CHANCE_OF_BRIDGE = 0.3F;

    public enum Tile {
        PAVEMENT,
        WATER,
        BRIDGE;
    }

    private final Tile[][] tiles;
    private final int xMax;
    private final int yMax;

    private final Random rng;

    public Board(int width, int heigth) {
        this.tiles = null;
        this.xMax = 0;
        this.yMax = 0;
        this.rng = null;

        setupBoard();
    }

    private void setupBoard() {
        // creates the tiles
    }

    private Tile chooseBridgeOrWater() {
        // TODO implement
        return null;
    }

    private boolean onEdge(int x, int y) {
        // TODO implement
        return false;
    }

    public Tile getTile(Position position) {
        // TODO implement
        return null;
    }

    public int getWidth() {
        // TODO implement
        return 0;
    }

    public int getHeight() {
        // TODO implement
        return 0;
    }
}

public enum Direction {
    LEFT, RIGHT, UP, DOWN;
}

public final class Mouse {

    public enum State {
        ALIVE,
        ESCAPED,
        DROWNED,
        STARVED;
    }

    private LinkedList<Position> trail = new LinkedList<Position>();
    private State state;


    public Mouse(Position startingPosition) {
        this.trail.add(startingPosition);
        this.state = State.ALIVE;
    }

    public void moveTo(Position newPosition) {
        this.trail.add(newPosition);
    }

    public Position getPosition() {
        return trail.getLast();
    }

    public void setState(State state) {
        this.state = state;
    }

    public State getState() {
        return state;
    }

    public List<Position> getTrail() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableList(trail); 
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("Mouse is %s at %s", getState(), getPosition());
    }
}

public class MouseGame {
    private static final int NUM_ROWS = 10;
    private static final int NUM_COLS = 15;
    private static final int MAX_MOVES = 50;

    private Random rng = new Random();
    private Board board;
    private Mouse mouse;

    private int round;
    private Position initialMousePosition;
    private List<Direction> moves;

    public MouseGame() {

    }

    public void setup() {
        board = new Board(NUM_ROWS, NUM_COLS);
        initialMousePosition = createRandomPositionInArea(1, board.getWidth() - 1, 1, board.getHeight() - 1);
        mouse = new Mouse(initialMousePosition);
        initialMousePosition = mouse.getPosition();
        moves = new LinkedList<Direction>();
    }

    public Position createRandomPositionInArea(int xLo, int xHi, int yLo, int yHi) {
        return null;
    }

    private Direction randomDirection() {
        // TODO implement
        return null;
    }

    private Position moveTo(Position oldPosition, Direction direction) {
        // TODO implement
        return null;
    }

    public boolean performRound() {
        // TODO implement
        return false;
    }

    public void printBoard(PrintStream out) {
        // prints the board in the current state (never implemented this)
        // but you go over all the positions in the board
        // and then check if the mouse or trail has been there and print that instead of the "tile"
    }

    public Mouse getMouse() {
        return mouse;
    }


    private static Mouse.State performGame() {
        MouseGame game = new MouseGame();
        game.setup();
        boolean finished = false;
        while (!finished) {
            finished = game.performRound();
        }

        return game.getMouse().getState();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int drownCount = 0;
        int starveCount = 0;
        int escapeCount = 0;

        int games = 1_000_000_000;

        var start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (int i = 0; i < games; i++) {
            Mouse.State finalState = performGame();
            switch (finalState) {
            case DROWNED:
                drownCount++;
                break;
            case ESCAPED:
                escapeCount++;
                break;
            case STARVED:
                starveCount++;
                break;
            default:
                throw new IllegalStateException();
            }
        }
        var end = System.currentTimeMillis();

        System.out.printf("Escaped: %d, Drowned: %d, Starved: %d%n", escapeCount, drownCount, starveCount);
        System.out.printf("Running time in ns per game (including board setup): %d%n", ((end - start) * 1_000_000) / games);

    }
}

package com.stackexchange.so.mouse.show;

public final class Position {
    private final int x;
    private final int y;

    public Position(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("(%d, %d)", x, y);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, i fixed that but now i dont know how to change the location of the "mouse"

Comment: if (move == 1)//up
                      {
                      
                       island[x][y] = island[x][y+1];
            `

Comment: I'd first create a `nextX` and `nextY`, then perform the assignment, and finally do `x = nextX` and `y = nextY`. As you do it you still don't change `x` and `y` themselves.

Comment: Could you explain that in detail please? Where would i put the x = nextX?

Comment: You create a temp variables nextX, nextY when you decide where to move to and then assign x, y after each move you perform on the board (if you keep to the current design anyway).

Comment: I'm unfortunately out of time, it's over 1 AM here. Tomorrow is a new day.

Comment: *New problems generally require new questions.* Try and focus on the specific functionality in the question that fails, and roll back the last edit of your question.